# Pipenv should not inherit global environment variables

Tags: python, pipenv

For my python project, I am using Pipenv. On my local computer I have a bunch of AWS environment variables, that I don't want my virtual environment to use.

Each time my pipenv shell starts, I unset the variables - But for some reason, after each computer restart, upon activating the pipenv shell, I can see that the environment variables from my "parent" are being injected into the virtual environment.

Is there any way to disable this behavior, so that no environment variables are spilled over to my pipenv?

Comment: If you change some state and then restart the computer, of course you lose it!  Env vars are here behaving properly.  Subshells should inherit them from their parent env; that's the whole point.  However, you can unset them in the launching script.  How are you launching the env?  And what is this for? (Secrets in env vars are pretty vulnerable already)

Comment: While this probably is correct, I was wondering if there is a way to at least specify which vars to either in- or exclude - without writing a custom script for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any way to disable this behavior, so that no environment variables are spilled over to my pipenv?

This behavior can't simply be disabled because it is fundamental to how Unix processes work: a child process inherits the environment from the parent process. There are a few ways we can approach your question; the easiest is probably taking advantage of pipenv's support for [loading `.env` files](https://pipenv-fork.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced.html#automatic-loading-of-env). If a `.env` file exists in the root of your `pipenv` project, then `pipenv` will load it whenever it runs.

So for example if in our parent environment we have:

```
SOMEVAR=somevalue
ANOTHERVAR=anothervalue
export SOMEVAR ANOTHERVAR
```

Normally, if we start a `pipenv shell` we will see those values in the new environment:

```
$ pipenv shell
$ env | grep -E 'SOMEVAR|ANOTHERVAR'
ANOTHERVAR=anothervalue
SOMEVAR=somevalue
```

But if we override those with empty values in a `.env` file:

```
$ cat > .env <<EOF
> SOMEVAR=
> ANOTHERVAR=
> EOF
```

Then that will take precedence when we start `pipenv shell`:

```
$ pipenv shell
$ env | grep -E 'SOMEVAR|ANOTHERVAR'
ANOTHERVAR=
SOMEVAR=
```

Comment: @JeppeChristensen however *don't* rely on this for active security.  A security model where you have to actively blacklist secrets is very dangerous.  If it matters that those env vars don't spill over, set them up in a limited env which standard shells *don't* inherit from (probably using a .env file, e.g. for docker).  Use this only if it's 'an annoyance to have all those vars', not 'potentially untrusted code will have access to secrets'.  Or at the very least have the blacklist generated in the same step which populates the env, but *you really don't want to do this*.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answers, clears things up. @2e0byo yes, this is fortunately mostly for development, so no harm done thus far :-)

Comment: @JeppeChristensen 'only for development' only scares me further ;)  I really can't stress enough that *anything in global env vars* should be considered public.  It's so easy to push security to tomorrow, and tomorrow never comes....  Still, you know what your application is.